# Can muggles cross through the barrier at kings cross?

Tags: harry-potter

I mean it would make sense if they couldn't but, how could the barrier tell the difference between a muggle born wizard and a normal muggle because i'm guessing people would tend to lean on the big pillars, and kids would fall on them..

Comment: There are lots of spells that can detect whether someone has magic or not, e.g., the Muggle-repelling charms on Hogwarts.

Comment: Telling muggle from witch/wizard is one thing, muggle repelling charms and such exist, but a more interesting question would be how to get the barrier to tell a random-passerby-muggle from a muggleborn-parent-muggle.

Comment: ooo yes, thanks a lot, im going to post a question like this now, again thanks!!!!

Comment: also, sorry i didnt see the duplicate :(